# Установка coreui, без node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Имеется сервер apach. Создал страницу с подключением bootstrap, как подключить, установить coreui на свой проект, поверх bootstrap? Установка описанная на официальном подразумевает включает себя наличие сервера на node.js. Однако сервер на апаче уже есть, потому смысла добавлять сюда еще node не вижу. Есть ли какой-то путь установиться coreui без node.js и танцев с бубном устанавливая node, gulp и прочее? В идеале, что-то типа

```
<script>/path/bootstrap.js</script>
<script>/path/coreui.js</script>
```

Помимо bootstrap не планирую использовать другие инструменты angular,react и проч.

Comment: Он и не просит от вас установки node.js на сервер, просто сейчас весь фронт собирается через "танцы с бубном". И недалек тот день, когда и бутстрепа в сборе не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, у них есть [инструкция](https://coreui.io/docs/getting-started/introduction/), как быстро добавить `coreui` в свой проект
Раздел:

> Add CoreUI to an existing project

Или просто скачиваете все нужны файлы и подключаете к себе, указывая путь к файлам на сервере